# JDeveloper 10 Freezes on my Dell 6520

Tags: java, jdeveloper

On my Dell 6520 JDeveloper freezes temporarily during use. It usually happens whenever I scroll through the editor. It spends more time freezing than actually reading through the documents. This happens so much that all of the developers on my team have resorted to using NotePad++. This is not the best solution for obvious reasons. Upgrading to the latest version (11g) is also not an option for us at this time.

It appears to be due to video faults happening during scrolling. I have checked through Dell's site for video driver updates but it seems that my

Comment: Are you running a 64bit OS?

Comment: Yes I'm running Windows 7 Enterprise 64 bit

Comment: It seems that changing my resolution to a lower resolution fixes the problem as a work around now. Until I find the real solution I think I will go with this temporary solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's a known bug with JDev 10g that it does not perform well on 64 bit systems.  Here are some things you can try

1. You can use a different JRE.  JDeveloper includes it's own JRE, which is very likely a 32bit JRE.  You can try installing a 64-bit JRE and using that with JDeveloper.  This means installing JDeveloper with the platform independent installer rather than the Windows installer.
2. Run it in a VM.  Running a 32bit XP-VM might be a reasonable stop gap solution.  Alternatively, install a 32bit version of Windows/Linux and develop on that in the mean time.
3. Upgrade to JDeveloper 11g.  I understand you can't, but it's time to start planning for the migration.  Alternative, is to move to something like Eclipse for development and use [OEPE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/downloads/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Old topic I know, but I just encountered this issue with `JDev 10.1.3` and placing this here to help others.

A guy running JDeveloper on Windows using a laptop had serious problems with the display when the IDE tried to scroll as it was leaving visible marks. It ended up that the remedy was adding `AddVMOption -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true` at the `$JDEV_HOME/jdev/bin/jdev.conf` file.

http://abakalidis.blogspot.com/2007/06/jdeveloper-1013x-screen-display.html